# How to limit a d3 line-chart from showing the line outside of the range of the axis?

Tags: d3.js

I have a d3 line chart with a time-based x-axis. I want to show 2 days worth of data, going from the last measurement (as in: the latest in time) to 2 days before that, even if there is more data than that. This works.

To allow the user to see the data that doesn't appear, I have a zoom behaviour (which doesn't allow zooming, only panning on the x-axis). This also works.

The issue I now face is that when I have data that goes out of the range of the axis (either the x or the y axis), it's still plotted up to the boundary of the svg. I want to limit the visible line to the area of the svg bounded by the axis.

I've got a [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/tjc2z5zp/1/), where you can see the issue. Data is shown left of the x-axis and higher than the maximum value of the y-axis, neither is desired. I'm not sure why it's doing this, or how I can stop it. E.g. my y scale:

```
yScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([41.5, 34.5]),
```

But when a value 43 is given, it still tries to plot it. Same issue on the x-axis. I'm sure it must be possible to limit the data that is shown, because [this guy managed](http://computationallyendowed.com/blog/2013/01/21/bounded-panning-in-d3.html) it. Unfortunately I haven't found the code with which the lower 2 charts on that page are being generated.

Comment: You need to create a [clipPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath) to mask the trendline path. You can see how it's done in the example you linked to, by viewing source and searching for "clipper".

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction @meetamit, didn't know about that element! I got a weird result trying to replicate the way it was set up in the link you provided - it did [this](http://jsfiddle.net/rc38dLqu/2/). But when I tried to do it as in the site I mentioned (after searching for clipper like you said), I got it to work.

Answer (score 7):

You can limit which points are displayed using `defined`

Every sample gets passed through the function and where it returns false, the points aren't shown...

```
var line = d3.line()
    .defined(function(d) { 
       return d.x < xMax && dx > xMin && d.y > yMin && d.y< yMax; 
    })
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.x); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.y); });
```

Alternatively, you can use a `clip-path` like [in this example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4015254).

Comment: As Tim suggested in his alternative, I used Mr Bostock's clipPath approach to stop lines at the axes that were misbehaving by crossing the X/Y axes on their way out to the border of the .svg. As Mike's example shows, there are two parts, attaching the clipping rectangle to the svg and then attaching a reference to each path you draw as in: .attr("clip-path", "url(#clip)")

Answer (score 1):

What i did was, I divided the data values by multiples of 10 through trial and error.
I think d3 would just plot data out of it's range if it's too large, because once I divided the values they were scaled perfectly.

```js
.append("circle")
                    .attr('cx', d => xScale(d.foreign_investement/10000))
                    .attr('cy', d => yScale(d.earnings/1000))
```

However, my data was fixed and I was not planning to scale up my graph. The clipPath would be the ideal solution for me too but I don't know how to use it yet.